# How to play audio with SoundManager 2 threeSixtyPlayer?

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

Currently I worked on audio system and I want to use SoundManager 2 360 player.
There are **soundManager** and **threeSixtyPlayer** objects.

**threeSixtyObject** is an object that represent *360 player*.
I know how to play audio with **soundManager**: just use  `createSound` function and then `sound.play()`. There is possibility to stop, play, repeat and so on with **soundmanager**.

So, my question is: *How to play audio via theeeSixtyPlayer in JavaScript?*.
Currentrly I can only create 360 player UI and pause/play only one audio by the HTML markup. I don't know how to change/pause/stop/play audio, how to add new audio (aka how to create playlist) via JavaScript for 360 audioplayer.

Can you provide some examples or documentation for SoundManager2 360 player?

Comment: Tryu [bar-ui.js](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/) and see how it manipulates the soundmanager interface, you may even like bar-ui.js